# where does go write panic logs?

Tags: logging, go

I installed golang on a redhat server through epel. I'm trying to analyze the panic logs but I can't find where the logs are stored. Any hint ? There is no trace in /var/log

```
      func main() {

            http.HandleFunc("/", panicRecover(test))
            log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
        }



    func test(){
        out, err := exec.Command("echo ", "something").Output()
            if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)

            }
    }


func panicRecover(f func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer func() {
            if r := recover(); r != nil {
                log.Printf("PANIC RECOVERED:%s\n", r)
            }
        }()
        f(w, r)
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To `stderr`.

For example,

```
package main

import "log"

func main() {
    log.Panic("log.Panic to stderr")
}


$ go run panic.go 2>stderr.txt
```

`stderr.txt` File:

```
2014/06/09 00:30:54 log.Panic to stderr
panic: log.Panic to stderr

goroutine 16 [running]:
runtime.panic(0x497180, 0xc2080001a0)
    /home/peter/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:279 +0xf5
log.Panic(0x7f88770fff20, 0x1, 0x1)
    /home/peter/go/src/pkg/log/log.go:307 +0xb6
main.main()
    /home/peter/gopath/src/so/panic.go:6 +0xa7

goroutine 17 [runnable]:
runtime.MHeap_Scavenger()
    /home/peter/go/src/pkg/runtime/mheap.c:507
runtime.goexit()
    /home/peter/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445

goroutine 18 [runnable]:
bgsweep()
    /home/peter/go/src/pkg/runtime/mgc0.c:1976
runtime.goexit()
    /home/peter/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445

goroutine 19 [runnable]:
runfinq()
    /home/peter/go/src/pkg/runtime/mgc0.c:2606
runtime.goexit()
    /home/peter/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445
exit status 2
```

Comment: I'm wondering where it goes if it runs as a http server ( see the example I provided )

Comment: To stderr (still). You can either create your own log.Logger and write to a file, or use a process manager like Supervisor to re-direct stdout and stderr to a log file and rotate it as needed.